# :hover command won't work with a general sibling selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to have a display that changes when hovering a div class. The idea is to have one div disappear when hovering another. I have tried using general sibling selectors to make the display change from inline to none. The CSS is as follows:

```
#Inicio {width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline;
    }

.buttons:hover ~ #Inicio {display: none;}

.buttons {width: 80%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        position: static;
        margin-left: 10%;
        font-size: 22px;
        border-top: 1px solid white;
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 20px; }

.buttons:hover {font-size: 24px;
            transition: all .5s ;}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="menubar">
    <div id="menu">
        <h1>Menu</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        Inicio
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        Productos
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        Localizacion
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        El equipo
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        Ideas
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        La pagina
    </div>
</div>

    <div id="content">
    <div id="inicio"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: please show your html as well

Comment: You cannot select the previous element in CSS so you can do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/JNJPh/) and also, you have `inicio` and you are using `Inicio` in CSS

Comment: Aren't element ids case sensitive? Did you try `.buttons:hover ~ #inicio {display: none;}` ?

Comment: yes, sorry about that. That was a typo when uploading it onto stack overflow. Thanks for the idea though.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, your `id` names doesn't match, its case sensitive, you `#inicio` and `#Inicio` are completely two different things..

And as [I commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21089701/hover-command-wont-work-with-a-general-sibling-selector/21089864?noredirect=1#comment31722435_21089701), the issue is that you cannot pop out of the element using CSS means you cannot select the parent element and than go ahead and select the parents sibling element, so you need to change your DOM, you are trying to select an element which is adjacent to the buttons parent element and not the button itself, so the best you can do is this

```
.buttons:hover ~ #content > #inicio {
    display: none;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JNJPh/)

---

Altered DOM, you need to bring the elements on the same level, if `#inicio` is nested, it's fine, but to select it's parent, bring the elements adjacent to each other on the same level so that all are direct child to an element having an `id` of `#wrapper`

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu">
        <h1>Menu</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        Inicio
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        Productos
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="inicio">Disappear this</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

As [@enguerranws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21089701/hover-command-wont-work-with-a-general-sibling-selector/21089931?noredirect=1#comment31722706_21089931) commented, I thought to put a compatibility table as well,

[image]

<sup>[Credits](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/generalsiblingselector) - Support Table</sup>

Comment: Best way to do that I think. What about compatibility ?

Comment: @enguerranws totally compatible :)

Comment: Works in IE8 ? IF so, great snippet.

Comment: @enguerranws Added the compatibility chart :)

Comment: Nice. It's good to have this chart as the "~" operator is described as supported by IE7+. But I knew there was some bugs when it's combined to :hover and some elements.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe because it's `#inicio`, not `#Inicio` ?

Then you need to change your DOM. You have to put #inicio in .buttons div. Or :

```
.buttons:hover ~ #Inicio
```

Won't work.

```
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="menubar">
<div id="menu">
    <h1>Menu</h1>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
    <span>Inicio</span>
    <div id="inicio"></div>

</div>

</div>

<div id="content">

</div>

</div>
```

You should use that structure. Btw, I added a span to wrap your text, as it's not valid to put text directly in block element (here: div).

Comment: nope, he needs to change the DOM - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21089701/hover-command-wont-work-with-a-general-sibling-selector/21089864?noredirect=1#comment31722435_21089701

Comment: Selectors are case sensitive. And yeah, his selector .buttons:hover ~ #Inicio can't do the job.